# Problem with swap in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: swap, 19.10

Ubuntu 19.10 feels very very lagging. I was using 19.04 and did a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10 but the new installation is much much slow and lagging. I have a system with 2 Gb of RAM and it was usable with Regolith DE and Ubuntu 19.04. But Ubuntu 19.10 starts hanging after just 4 to 5 Firefox tabs. On disabling swapping, the performance improved but in the absence of swap file, on filling the ram, system not only lags but stucks for ever. Disabling swapping is not a convenient solution for a system with 2 Gb of ram. This lags and hanging when swapping enabled is completely absent in Ubuntu 19.04. Help me to solve the issue or I don't have an option other than downgrading to older 19.04.

Comment: When you adjusted swappiness, did you adjust it the correct way?   *The last post I saw on this site had the user adjust swappiness the opposite way to what they'd intended*  Providing details of what you did may allow more specific answers/suggestions

Comment: I'd also check you haven't made changes to partitions (eg. re-formatted your swap partition meaning the entry in your fstab (file system table) is invalid...)

Comment: @guiverc i have recreated swap file several times by following the instructions from    [ https://itsfoss.com/create-swap-file-linux/ ]

Comment: Sorry I'm not going to critique a unofficial site's instructions (*official no problem, if it was wrong I can fix it!*), maybe try `grep swap /etc/fstab; blkid` then compare UUID in fstab to that your partitions ... etc

Comment: Please don't add extra detail in comments, edit your question and put it there (*greater formatting options are provided, plus we can edit to improve it if required; comments can only be deleted*).

Comment: Also include systemspecs, including how much ram you have. Is the hard drive a conventional (magnetic rotating) one or an SSD?

Comment: @guiverc The thing is i reinstalled 19.10 and with default settings , the lag is present . And i'm pretty sure that 19.04 was much much usable with default settings.

Comment: GNOME is not my *cup-of-tea* and thus rarely use it.  I prefer LXQt (Lubuntu) or XFCE (Xubuntu) myself, but I do know GNOME is faster on 19.10 than on 19.04, though not everyone will detect it as it'll depend on your CPU if you gain the benefits (see vanvugt's post https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/boosting-the-real-time-performance-of-gnome-shell-3-34-in-ubuntu-19-10/). Yes I agree something is wrong with your setup; if you clean installed I'd check your hardware; if you didn't format it'll likely be user configs (ie. /home/ can be kept during re-install meaning user config problems remain)

Comment: This was a kernal bug .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the problems vanished after installing kernel version 5.0. Now my system is very responsive just like it was when I had Ubuntu 19.04. 
I tried installing the latest  kernel and I got less lags than untouched Ubuntu 19.10 but the system was super fine with 5.0. I felt a more stable experience with Version 5.0 than in any other latest kernels.

Update : issue little gone with kernel 5.5.6