# Ubuntu 19.10 thrashing frequently with browser activity

Tags: swap, 19.10

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 on both a desktop and a laptop and they seem to have the same problem.  My kernel is

```
5.3.0-26-generic
```

My sysctl.conf swap settings are

```
vm.swappiness=10
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

Here's the result of free when the issue is not happening

```
            total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7897212     4311104     1014720      992380     2571388     2290352
Swap:       4194300      576796     3617504
```

What happens is, I'll be working along, I'll open a new browser tab, doesn't matter if it's chrome or firefox, i've tried both, and suddenly I experience lag.  I move my mouse, then the cursor moves a half a second later.  On my desktop, I can see that it's disk activity, b/c the LED lights up.  This happens all the time, I cannot seem to make it happen at will though.  In the few times that I've been able to get back to the console in time to run top and hit 'm', I see that I have about 10-15% of memory and 10-20% of swap free.  Both machines have 8gig of memory.

It seems to me that 8 gig of memory is more than enough to run Ubuntu, and I don't think the solution is "get more memory."  I've seen other posts that indicated that the issue was in the kernel (for example [Problem with swap in Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197236/problem-with-swap-in-ubuntu-19-10)), but I'm already in 5.3.

Please let me know if you need additional info and thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: I've made a minor correction in my answer. Please note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "only" 8G RAM, these settings:

```
vm.swappiness=10
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

are totally wrong.

Set them to:

```
vm.swappiness=80
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=100
```

---

Set them this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

---

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=80`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=80` at the end of the file

---

Search for an existing `vfs_cache_pressure=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vfs_cache_pressure

- If found, **edit** it to say `vfs_cache_pressure=100`
- If not found, **add** `vfs_cache_pressure=100` at the end of the file

---

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`

And report back.

Comment: Things are way better now - much less lagginess, but the hard drive LED is on 100% of the time - it's always doing something.  Not sure if it's harmful or not but seems like it's off a little.

Comment: @user1130176 edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sysctl vm.vfs_cache_pressure`. Install `iotop` and see what's running your disk.

Comment: iotop revealed that it was dropbox, which  was unintentionally set to auto-start. I've disabled it and I'll see how things go for the next hour or so.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @user1130176 dropbox should only be doing I/O if it's syncing.

Comment: i just wanted to say thanks again, you've solved the problem, i am loving the speed of ubuntu once again, i really appreciate your help. If I could check the checkbox twice, I would.

Comment: @user1130176 Glad to hear the extra feedback! Remember to mod the other machine also :-)